# Print colnames with spaces

Tags: r

```
df = readRDS('mydata.RDS')
message('column names: ',colnames(df))
```

Output

```
column names: col1col2col2col4
```

How can I get it to print with spaces like

```
column names: col1 col2 col3 col4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `paste()`.  I used the `mtcars` data set and added a line-break.

```
message(
    "now have the following columns: ",
    paste(colnames(mtcars), collapse = " "), 
    "\nand the following rows: ", 
    nrow(mtcars)
)
# now have the following columns: mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
# and the following rows: 32
```